# how to generate a map based on a given scale [Bing Map]?

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, bing-maps, bing-api

I recently started working with **[*Bing Api*]** in my webService [wcf] in c #.
I would like to **recover a satellite image of a given scale** with Bing!
for example

Scale 1:200 (1 centimeter on the map equal 200 centimeters on the world)

Of course I found this function that explains how to calculate the image resolution satellite bing but this is not what I'm looking for ..

```
Map resolution = 156543.04 meters/pixel * cos(latitude) / (2 ^ zoomlevel)
```

Here is my function used to generate my bing map, but I do not know what to send parameter to retrieve an image scale of 1:200.

*I need :*

**Scale = 1:200**

*I search :*

int **mapSizeHeight** = ?

int **mapSizeWidth** = ?

int **zoomLevel** = ?

```
public string GetImageMap(double latitude,double longitude,int mapSizeHeight, int mapSizeWidth, int zoomLevel)
    {
        string key = "ddsaAaasm5vwsdfsfd2ySYBxfEFsdfsdfcFh6iUO5GI4v";
        MapUriRequest mapUriRequest = new MapUriRequest();

        // Set credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        mapUriRequest.Credentials = new ImageryService.Credentials();
        mapUriRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

        // Set the location of the requested image
        mapUriRequest.Center = new ImageryService.Location();
        mapUriRequest.Center.Latitude = latitude;
        mapUriRequest.Center.Longitude = longitude;

        // Set the map style and zoom level
        MapUriOptions mapUriOptions = new MapUriOptions();
        mapUriOptions.Style = MapStyle.Aerial;
        mapUriOptions.ZoomLevel = zoomLevel;
        mapUriOptions.PreventIconCollision = true;
        // Set the size of the requested image in pixels
        mapUriOptions.ImageSize = new ImageryService.SizeOfint();
        mapUriOptions.ImageSize.Height = mapSizeHeight;
        mapUriOptions.ImageSize.Width = mapSizeWidth;

        mapUriRequest.Options = mapUriOptions;

        //Make the request and return the URI
        ImageryServiceClient imageryService = new ImageryServiceClient();
        MapUriResponse mapUriResponse = imageryService.GetMapUri(mapUriRequest);
        return mapUriResponse.Uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, you might want to check out [this article on the Bing Maps tile system calculations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx), within you will find a section discussing ground resolution and map scale.  From that article:

```
map scale = 1 : ground resolution * screen dpi / 0.0254 meters/inch
```

Depending on which implementation of Bing Maps you use, specifying the view via a precise map scale might not be possible.  I think this is due to the fact that you don't have precise control over the zoom level.  For example, in the javascript ajax version, you can only specify zoom levels in integer values, so the `ground resolution` part of the above equation will jump in discreet steps.   At the equator, using a zoom level of `21` will give you a scale of `1: 282`, and a zoom level of `22` will give you `1:141`.  Since you can't specify a decimal value for zoom level, it is not possible to get an exact 1:200 scale using the ajax control.  I don't have extensive experience with the .net Bing Maps control, so you might want to investigate that API to see if you can specify an arbitrary zoom level.

If you can precisely control the zoom level and know the dpi value, then the 1:200 scale is achievable using the equation described in the above linked article.

Comment: I'm sorry but upon reflection, I do not see how it is possible to calculate the zoom, and the resolution of my image with a known scale .. I do not need to look scale because I already know  -> map scale = 1:200 but zoomLevel = ?..etc

Comment: The first thing to investigate is whether you can set the zoom level to a decimal value in your API.  If you can only set the zoom level to integral values, then you are stuck with the discreet steps of map scale defined in the link above.  You will then have to take the picture and manually scale it to your desired 1:200 scale.  Basically if you could set the zoom level to a decimal value, that work of scaling the image would have been done for you.  Keep in mind that the satellite image itself is taken at discreet scales, so any scale change from that will need to be done in software.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out the math to deriving the zoom level value given the map scale, you have all the equations and are only solving for one variable...

Comment: For the map dimensions, my understanding is that you can just pick square area of any allowed size in pixels, plug it into the equation and you will get a zoom level to reach 1:200 scale at that dimension.